# Convert a MatrixTransform3D into Transform3DGroup

Tags: wpf, 3d

what is the correct way to convert a MatrixTransform3D into Transform3DGroup in WPF?
I mean that given a MatrixTransform3D, create a TransformGroup3D containing a TranslateTransform3D, a ScaleTransform3D and a RotateTransform3D which are equivalent to the original MatrixTransform3D.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a similar problem. I did all the equations to generate the `Transformation Matrices`, and then when I started to do the code in C#, I started to realize that most of what I want to do I can do with the `ROtateTransform3D`,`TranslateTransform3D`, etc. 
For me, the solution was to:

- create a Transform3DGroup
- add the model pieces to that group    model.transform = transformGroup
- generate an axis angle rotation
- generate RotateTransform3D
- transformGroup3D.children.Add(rotatetransform)
- create a DoubleAnimation
- add animation to the AxisAngleRotation

Make sure to add the offest to the `ROtateTransform3D` for the point to rotate about...
I am not sure if these even helps, but it helped me to use the tools available and I have a pretty complex object that I am animating...